# Sorting all the grid data on column header click in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Platform : C# Winforms
IDE : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

I want to sort the whole data grid data on column click, but it sorts only the data which are visible on the page. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you saying only the visible rows in the grid are sorted and when you scroll down the rows are un-ordered. Is there paging involved?

Comment: No there is no paging involved ...